# I can not find geom_mosaic package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a mosaic plot, but I cannot find the package geom_mosaic. I updated ggplot2 but still nothing. Could you please give me a hint?. 
Thanks,
-Marzieh

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggmosaic")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("haleyjeppson/ggmosaic")

library(ggmosaic)
```